# Setting Image.Source doesn't update when loading from a resource

Tags: wpf, image, resources

I've got this definition in my XAML:

```
<Image Name="AlbumArt" Source="/AlbumChooser2;component/Resources/help.png" />
```

The image is display OK on startup.

In my code I'm looking for mp3's to play and I display the associated album art in this `Image`. Now if there's no associated image I want to display a "no image" image. So I've got one defined and I load it using:

```
BitmapImage noImage = new BitmapImage(
              new Uri("/AlbumChooser2;component/Resources/no_image.png",
                      UriKind.Relative));
```

I've got a helper class that finds the image if there is one (returning it as a `BitmapImage`), or returns null if there isn't one:

```
if (findImage.Image != null)
{
    this.AlbumArt.Source = findImage.Image; // This works
}
else
{
    this.AlbumArt.Source = noImage; // This doesn't work
}
```

In the case where an image is found the source is updated and the album art gets displayed. In the case where an image isn't found I don't get anything displayed - just a blank.

I don't think that it's the setting of `AlbumArt.Source` that's wrong, but the loading of the `BitmapImage`.

If I use a different image it works (e.g. the original help image), but even if I recreate the "no image" image it doesn't work. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas to think about/try:

What are the Visual Studio settings for no_image.png? Is it an "Embedded Resource" or "Content"? Do you have it set to "Copy Always" or "Copy If Newer"?

It looks like your referencing the image as a resource, but have you actually added it to your project's resources? If it is a resource, I believe you should set it the properties to "Resource" and "Copy Never".

What happens if you make your `UriKind` `UriKind.Absolute` and set the path to the actual file on disk?

If you look at `noImage` in the debugger at the point you're setting it to the `Source`, is it definitely non-null and does it have the correct width/height?

Comment: The image has been loaded and has the right height and width. The build action was "None" - setting it to "Resource" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

[Binding Bitmapimge to Image in Wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748930/binding-bitmapimge-to-image-in-wpf)

when wpf compile to .exe resource directory became part of your .exe and u cant access that from this code

```
BitmapImage noImage = new BitmapImage(
          new Uri("/AlbumChooser2;component/Resources/no_image.png",
                  UriKind.Relative))
```

so You must use this code `Resources.no_image.png` and convet that to BitmapImage.

Regards REV